# How to get transactions of specific token with web3.py?

Tags: web3.py

For example I want to get all the transactions made on Uniswap in the last 10 seconds where the token DAI was used for exchange . Is there a way to do this within web3.py?

Comment: Some services that can be used to resovle queries are TheGraph, Etherscan, Moralis, Alchemy. The alternative is to run your own indexer.